# Problemas com a div do rodapé

Tags: html, css

Bom dia galera,
Estou tendo problemas com a div do meu rodapé. Sempre que vou usando o atalho CTRL + (+), chega um momento que o rodapé fica preenchendo a parte final da página. Tem como eu resolver isso?
Segue abaixo o código código da página html:

```
<div id="footer">
    <div id="corpo">

        <div id="coluna1">
            Congregação São João - RJ<br>
            CNPJ: 27-001/11.280.416<br>
            CEP: 250-25-515<br>
            Rua: Santo Antônio, nº523<br>
            Centro - São João de Mereti/RJ

        </div>  

        <div id="coluna2">
            Congregação Pau Grande - Magé/RJ<br>
            CEP: 25.933-145<br>
            Rua: Lindsay Anderson, nº 15<br>
            Pau Grande - Magé/RJ

        </div>

        <div id="coluna2">
            Congregação Santa Inês - Vila Velha/ES<br>
            CEP: 29.108-041<br>
            Rua: Avenida Rui Braga Ribeiro, nº961<br>
            Santa Inês - Vila Velha/ES
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

E o css:

```
#footer {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -150px; /* valor negativo da altura do rodapé */
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    clear: both;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    background-position: center right;
    background-color: #7d0d0d;  
}

#textorodape{
    margin-right: 100px; 
    color: white; 
    font-size: 16px;
    position: center right; 
}

#coluna1 {
    float: left;
    width: 333px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 14px;
}

#coluna2 {
    float: left; 
    width: 333px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

Comment: Julio, acho que você poderia enviar o html também, pois não entendi onde está sendo utilizado coluna1 e coluna2, imagino #footer seja o id de uma div, mas o textorodape também é id ou é class? é usada em uma div?

Comment: Obrigado @EduardoMendes, essa textoropade é um id, mas não estou utilizando. Vou enviar o html, só um minuto!

Comment: @EduardoMendes, pronto, editado!

Answer (score 2):

Minha sugestão é utilizar o tamanho do [height](/questions/tagged/height) em porcentagem. Imagino que tenha outra [div](/questions/tagged/div) acima da [div](/questions/tagged/div) [footer](/questions/tagged/footer). No exemplo abaixo eu adicionei uma [div](/questions/tagged/div) chamada [conteudo](/questions/tagged/conteudo) e coloquei seu tamanho em porcentagem. Observe também que coloquei as tags [html](/questions/tagged/html) e [body](/questions/tagged/body) com o width e height em 100%. Então a [div](/questions/tagged/div) [conteudo](/questions/tagged/conteudo) com 85% e a [div](/questions/tagged/div) [footer](/questions/tagged/footer) com 15%. Desta forma, o zoom não irá influenciar no tamanho das [divs](/questions/tagged/divs), somente no tamanho da [fonte](/questions/tagged/fonte).

Veja o [css](/questions/tagged/css):

```
html, body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;  
}

#conteudo {
    width:100%;
    height:85%;
    background:#FFED00; 
}

#footer {
    position: relative;
    /*margin-top: -150px;*/ /* valor negativo da altura do rodapé */
    width: 100%;
    height: 15%;
    clear: both;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    background-position: center right;
    background-color: #7d0d0d;  
}

#textorodape{
    margin-right: 100px; 
    color: white; 
    font-size: 16px;
    position: center right; 
}

.coluna1 {
    float: left;
    width: 333px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.coluna2 {
    float: left; 
    width: 333px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

E aqui o [html](/questions/tagged/html)

```
<div id="conteudo"></div>

<div id="footer">
    <div id="corpo">

        <div class="coluna1">
            Congregação São João - RJ<br>
            CNPJ: 27-001/11.280.416<br>
            CEP: 250-25-515<br>
            Rua: Santo Antônio, nº523<br>
            Centro - São João de Mereti/RJ

        </div>  

        <div class="coluna2">
            Congregação Pau Grande - Magé/RJ<br>
            CEP: 25.933-145<br>
            Rua: Lindsay Anderson, nº 15<br>
            Pau Grande - Magé/RJ

        </div>

        <div class="coluna2">
            Congregação Santa Inês - Vila Velha/ES<br>
            CEP: 29.108-041<br>
            Rua: Avenida Rui Braga Ribeiro, nº961<br>
            Santa Inês - Vila Velha/ES
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

**Obs: Não é recomendável que tenha mais de um [id](/questions/tagged/id) no código [html](/questions/tagged/html), quando isso acontece o ideal é substituir por [class](/questions/tagged/class), no caso das [divs](/questions/tagged/divs) [coluna2](/questions/tagged/coluna2).**

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou corretamente!!

Comment: Beleza. Se você achar necessário, depois marque a resposta como útil e aceita lá como a melhor resposta. Abraços

Answer (score -2):

Você já experimentou deixar o css da seguinte maneira ?

`.footer {
    position:absolute;`

Com isso, o seu rodapé não irá mais ser alterado pelo zoom do navegador.